# how to open an Robj file in r?

Tags: r

I am trying to open an Robj file in r from a server.

I used `load(samplesheet.Robj)`

but when I used `head(samplesheet)` it said object Error: 'samplesheet' not found

Does any one have an idea?  p.s. I didn't save the Robj file,someone else did, so I don't know what was the original name it was saved.

Comment: Try setting `verbose` to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! just tried and it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `load` has an argument `verbose`, as the docs explain:

> `verbose`
>   should item names be printed during loading?

By setting it to `TRUE` you will get a character vector of the objects contained in the dataset file.

```
vec <- c(1, 4, 3, 9, 8, 2, 1, 6, 4, 1)

fourthDev <- function(x) {
    dev <- x-mean(x)
    mean(dev^4)^0.25
}

save(vec, fourthDev, file="load-test.RData")

load("load-test.RData", verbose=TRUE)
# Loading objects:
#   vec
#   fourthDev
```

Comment: Thank you! I used verbose as you suggested earlier and it worked!